# Am I being too bitchy or intolerant?

Tags: discussion

In reference to this question: [How can I recover deleted files shared with a linux VM?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228867/how-can-i-recover-deleted-files-shared-with-a-linux-vm)

I recognize that I can be short with "lazy-web" posters. Are my responses in my answer and/or comments too blunt or unhelpful? I'm not *trying* to be an ass, but I reviewed this post and realized I may be coming across pretty poorly, so I am asking for the more experienced community to weigh in...am I violating Wheaton's Law?

Comment: If you have to ask it, the answer is yes.

Comment: Comes across like you're being helpful to me, or at least are trying to help the OP. Didn't really detect any negativity w/ what you've written.

Comment: I'm with slm on this. I don't see any signs of bitchiness whatsoever. I guess the OP would be the person to ask but as far as I can tell you're perfectly civil and helpful.

Comment: Thanks everyone. And I am not in disagreement with @mikeserv either. I was on the fence, thus why I asked. Just trying not to be _THAT_ guy who is always a jerk...

Comment: I didn't say it was a bad thing, and I didn't even check to look into the post you were talking about. I don't mind being *THAT* guy - ask anybody. Sometimes you gotta bitch, and who can tolerate *everything*?

Comment: It's about Linux, so you need to ask yourself the question: "What would Linus do?"

Comment: Huh I was expecting an amusingly snarky post to review, and got ... a perfectly normal post without _any_ bitching, intolerance or snark whatsoever. It's not even borderline. Have I missed something?!

Comment: I seem to be in the minority, but I think his answer would be more appropriate as comments. A useful answer should provide specific details. That answer just says to use the normal file recovery procedures, but if the OP knew what those were he wouldn't have asked.

Comment: Your answer is neither curt nor smart-ass. It's an appropriate answer to the question.

Comment: @barmar that crossed my mind. However, no one else had answered at that point. In the past I have been baited (trolled?) into providing q-a back and forth in comments with a lazyweb poster (AskUbuntu, not here). I had no desire to do the same here. I guess my only reply to your comment is: it's like asking your family Doctor for advice on BioChem homework. He does have some exposure and knowledge in the area, if he went to medschool in the last 15-20 years. But it probably ain't his primary gig...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not at all. In fact, given the paucity of information provided in the question, it is a very good answer: it covers a range of scenarios, likely to be helpful to others who find themselves in a similar situation and is completely devoid of what would be otherwise understandable snark.

Is this a trap?

Comment: ...if caught, what do you lose?

Comment: @mikeserv Probs are your friedliness.

Comment: @sebb - i dont even own a fryer.

Comment: @mikeserv There you go - he got ya ;)

Answer (score 7):

Looking at the post and comparing it to my experience with USENET, I would say your tone is almost saintly, given that you have no overt or even covert ad-hominem attacks, or complaints about the "laziness of kids today", for example.

Writing a technical question is a skill, and pointing out that information is missing is a perfectly good, and super useful lesson to impart.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you were too quick to mark the question as a duplicate.  There is one critical piece of information (the poster is running Linux in a VM on Windows) that makes the answer potentially completely different.  Therefore the question is not a duplicate of "how to you undelete files on Linux".

Comment: The question can only be considered different if the OP states in his question that he tried to apply the existing answers and they didn't work for him because he's in a VM. When no evidence is present, [Occam's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) applies.

Comment: It's a good point. However, I don't believe I was one of there ppl who marked it duplicate.

Comment: And after double checking (my memory isn't always so good) I can confirm I did not mark it as duplicate.

Comment: @0xSheepdog Sorry to have implicated you erroneously as a duplicator :)  My point that the question shouldn't have been tagged as such, though, stands.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I believe you're missing the point.  The OP might have applied the existing answers, given up, and resigned himself to data loss, not realizing that there might be other options for recovering data from a virtual disk image.  If you're going to throw around philosophical heuristics, the appropriate ones here aren't Occam's Razor but [Grice's maxims of quantity and relation](http://www.sas.upenn.edu/~haroldfs/dravling/grice.html).

Comment: @dodgethesteamroller, In the hypothetical situation "OP might have applied the existing answers, given up, and resigned himself to data loss" the issue lies in the lack of communication from the OP who failed to read [the first paragraph of this page](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), not in the fact that other people are bitchy and unhelpful. So in a way he's also broken the maxim of quantity you're siting, by not providing information about what he tried before asking. A more probable situation, however, is that the OP didn't do any research and didn't try anything.

Answer (score 1):

My impression is that you've been descriptive. Concise and determined, but not arrogant and downward-looking. I would just suggest to start a post with 'Hi!' simply to give it a gentle feel at the outset. Perhaps this can also help you feel better about your own approach. Good that you put yourself into discussion!

Comment: SE, especially technical subsites, is aimed at discussion of specifics, not socialising. I'm all for folk having fun if they like, but (across the web) I don't like the idea that we _should_ inflate all posts with platitudes, to placate people who expect constant pats on the head. It risks fuelling an unrealistic expectation of constant affirmation. And - rare in a situation like this - it's not just me! See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: The post @underscore_d mentions is interesting and shows that a curt approach has been debated/debatable. Socializing has more dimensions that a two-letter word on a SE forum. I see little risk not see the wheat from the chaff. I appreciate the risk of inflation though. The reference to [Grice's maxims of quality, quantity, relation and manner](http://www.sas.upenn.edu/~haroldfs/dravling/grice.html) is very apt (thx @dodgethesteamroller). Also, [Leech's politeness maxims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politeness_maxims) may give clues on how expectations shape our way to relate with others.